# Run php script with PHP-FPM

Tags: php

I have just installed nginx and php-fpm according to this
http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/
I am now visiting a php webpage and the php code is not been rendered

```
<?php echo 'test' ?>
```

Comment: What result do you get? Do the nginx error log show anything? Does something like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` show anything? What does the access log for nginx show? Does view source show the actual PHP source code? Have you tried setting display_errors = 1, error_reporting = E_ALL?

Comment: It shows the actual php source code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related with nginx configuration not php-fpm itself.

Nginx needs to be configured to let him now what to do with each file type. By default it is throwing files as static (the result is the raw content of the file as you report).

An basic example of nginx routing to set php-fpm as fast-cgi service for *.php files would be:

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
         ....

 location ~ \.php$ {
 try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm/DOMAINNAME.socket;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
 }
}
```

Check this basic example: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-nginx-and-php-fpm-running-on-unix-file-sockets/

If you want more advanced examples:

- This nginx.conf for Symfony (app.php is the Symfony2 bootstrap file).
  https://gist.github.com/leon/3019026
- Lumen use case.  https://gist.github.com/psgganesh/8d1790dd0c16ab5a4cde

And if you are interested in a deeper learning:

- Nginx documentation for Location:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location